# Draw the plane x+y=1 in three dimensions in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I want to draw the plane x+y=1 in pgfplots. In this example, z is free and
is not explicitly a function of x and y. So I cannot use

```
\addplot3[surf, fill=blue, opacity=0.1, fill opacity=0.4] {z=whatever};
```

I cannot parametrize the plane either, because the following syntax, instructing to take z to be free does not work:

```
\addplot3[surf, fill=blue, opacity=0.1, fill opacity=0.4] {x,-x+1,{}};
```

How can I do that? Perhaps by using scope and switching x and z axes, so that I can use one of the above standard syntax.

Comment: Is this all you want to plot? Or together with other elements? You could do The first version with 1 - x and exchange the y and z axis labels.

Comment: There are other graphs too. Can't just change labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,grid=major]
    \addplot3[name path=toppath,fill=blue, opacity=0.1, fill opacity=0.4,samples=2] (x,-x+1,5);
    \addplot3[name path=botpath,fill=blue, opacity=0.1, fill opacity=0.4,samples=2] (x,-x+1,-5);
    \addplot [gray] fill between[of=toppath and botpath];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]